# Why does my program not quit after I input "q"?

Tags: python-3.x

I just started learning to code in python and here is my first program. Why doesn't quit program when I enter the letter "q".

```
print("bu program sıcaklığa göre suyun durumunu gösterir")

while True:
    
   s=input("lütfen sıcaklığı giriniz.çıkmak içn q ya bas")
    
    
   if s=="q":
        print("çıkılıyor")

        break
    


   try:

        s_int=int(s)
        
   except ValueError:

        print("Lütfen sadece sayı giriniz")
        raise

    
   if s_int<0:
        
        print("Durum Buzdur")

   elif s_int>=100:

        print("Durum Buhar")

   else:

        print("Durum su")
```

Comment: "q" ain't no integer I ever heard of :~)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s=int(input("lütfen sıcaklığı giriniz"))
```

It's not possible for `s` to be equal to an alphabetical character `"q"`, if you are immediately converting your input to an `int` (an int is a number).

If anything your program should immediately jump to line `print("Lütfen sadece sayı giriniz")` because attempting to convert a `"q"` to an integer raises a `ValueError`.

To fix this, you could first compare the raw input to `"q"`. If it's not equal, then the next step you try converting it to an int.

```
s=input("lütfen sıcaklığı giriniz")

if s=="q":
    print("çıkılıyor")
    break

try:
    s_int = int(s)
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a valid integer or 'q'")
    raise

if s_int<0:
    print("Durum Buzdur")
elif s_int>=100:
    print("Durum Buhar")
else:
    print("Durum su")
```

Comment: Thanks Martin appreciated